# Softkeyboard pushes whole layout to the top

Tags: android, user-interface, android-softkeyboard

I am working on an app in which I have implemented the live video broadcasting,  and have a feature to place a live comment just like a Facebook live video feature. The problem I am facing is with EditTextView for comments. When Soft Keyboard appears on the screen It pushes the layout to the top.

I have tried to `adjustResize`, `adjsutPan` & adjust Nothing properties in Manifest. But these properties doesn't fulfill the UI requirement. What I want is to just move EditTextView to the top of Soft Keyboard and the rest of the layout as it is.

Layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true">

    <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
        android:id="@+id/camera_view_renderer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_gradient" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
            layout="@layout/header_layout" />


        <com.lts.localee.customViews.LTextView
            android:id="@+id/my_points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <com.lts.localee.customViews.PointsRangeComponent
            android:id="@+id/points_range_component"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="120dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#AA2f3c43"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/livePredQuestionGameSubBaseContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false" />

        <com.lts.localee.customViews.LTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_prediction_pressed"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="sadas"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.lts.localee.customViews.TriviaCommentComponent
        android:id="@+id/comments_component"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me out to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ` try this into your root Layout at the XMLfile.

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN,     check this one

Comment: @Sniffer I have tried this but not working

Comment: @notTdar Adjust Pan will push the layout to the top, I have already tried this property.

Comment: please post your xml layout

Comment: well, try android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in xml and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in manifest, remove other attributes

Answer (score 0):

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` inside your manifest

Comment: These properties are  not working in my case. Please see the question I have added the xml layout code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize` didn't help you, I think it's better to use `<ScrollView>` in your XML file